# serverless offline start hot reload not working

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-offline

I am unable to hot reload when using `serverless offline start`.

Here is my serverless.yml file

```
service: function-with-environment-variables

frameworkVersion: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
 
plugins:
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  register:
    handler: handler.register
    events:
      - http:
          path: /register
          method: post

  login:
    handler: handler.login
    events:
      - http:
          path: /login
          method: post

  verify:
    handler: handler.verify
    events:
      - http:
          path: /verify
          method: post
```

I have also tried using `sls offline start` still facing same error.

Here is the output of `serverless --version`

> `Running "serverless" from node_modules
> Framework Core: 3.24.1 (local) 3.24.1 (global)
> Plugin: 6.2.2
> SDK: 4.3.2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using this command to start your server:

```
serverless offline start --reloadHandler
```

`reloadHandler` Reloads handler with each request. More info here:
https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/864#issuecomment-1190950178

Comment: according to the doc https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline
`reloadHandler`  "Reloads handler with each request".

It does not watch for change, this is very slow.